# Using cookies from chromium, in headless mode

Tags: node.js, chromium, puppeteer

When I navigate through a site with Chromium, several cookies are stored and used. However, Puppeteer doesn't pick up on these when it runs Chromium in headless mode.

How can these cookies be used or transferred to the instance used by Puppeteer?

As a note, I do have `executablePath` set to the path where Chromium resides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to point puppeteer to [User data directory](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md) which contains all of the metadata, including bookmarks, history and cookies:

```
puppeteer.launch({
  executablePath : '...',
  userDataDir: '/path/to/user-data-directory',
})
```